# Zoom and Moving based on audio information in FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, visualizer, audio-analysis

I recently wondered if it is possible to zoom or move things in FFMPEG based on an audio source.

I already played around with `complex filters` as they allow some audio visualization but didn't really manage to move/zoom things based on sound. See good examples of complex filters used for audio visualization at: https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/ffmpeg/audio_visualization/index.html

My current situation is that i have multiple inputs which one of should react on sound/maybe even on special frequency's.